# Unable to bind model to template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-templates

I'm attempting to build a directive to handle the rendering of a repeating list of speakers. The end goal here is to have the page automatically reflect the updates made in a modal.

The problem I'm appearing to see here is that the `speakers` object doesn't appear to make it into the template.

This is the function that populates `speakers`. It's called in the modal's promise.  `speakers` is a collection of `speaker` objects. The data comes back as expected.

```
$scope.updateSpeakersList = function () {
    factory.callGetService("GetSpeakers?eventId=" + $scope.event.eventId)
        .then(function (response) {
            var fullResult = angular.fromJson(response);
            var serviceResponse = JSON.parse(fullResult.data);

            $scope.speakers = serviceResponse.Content;

            if ($scope.speakers === null) {
                $scope.hasSpeakers = false;
            } else {
                $scope.hasSpeakers = ($scope.speakers.length > 0);
            }

            LogErrors(serviceResponse.Errors);
        },
        function (data) {
            console.log("Unknown error occurred calling GetSpeakers");
            console.log(data);
        });
}

// other code... then this

modalInstance.result.then(function (savedSpeaker) {
    console.log("BEGIN modalInstance.result");
    $scope.savedSpeaker = savedSpeaker;
    console.log("$scope.savedSpeaker = " + $scope.savedSpeaker);

    $scope.updateSpeakersList();
    console.log("END modalInstance.result");
}, function () {
    console.log("Modal dismissed at: " + new Date());
});
```

The HTML looks like this.

```
<div class="container" ng-show="hasSpeakers">
    <div class="row">
        <speaker-cards data="speakers"></speaker-cards>
    </div>
</div>
```

The directive is pretty simple.

```
.directive("speakerCards", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "/Apps/Event/Templates/_default/speaker-cards.html",
        scope: {
            data: "="
        }
    };
});
```

The "speaker cards" template is a bit more complex than this, but you should get the point.

```
<!-- BEGIN speaker cards -->
<div ng-repeat="speaker in speakers | orderBy: 'SpeakerName'">
    <div class="clearfix" ng-if="$index % 3 == 0"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="card">
            <span class="speaker-name">{{speaker.SpeakerName}}</span><br/>
            <span class="speaker-title">{{speaker.CompanyTitle}}</span><br/>
            <span class="speaker-company">{{speaker.CompanyName}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END speaker cards -->
```

Besides the speakers not appearing, the reason I don't think that `speakers` is making it into the template, is because the resulting markup looks like this.

[image]

Comment: the speakercards directive doesn't seem to have a `speaker`-property on `$scope`. Either change `speaker in speakers` to `speaker in data` or change the 'data' property to speakers: `scope: {speakers: "=data"}`. see if that makes any difference.

Comment: @Gustav Such a simple thing... that fixed it. I made the attribute "speakers" in the element.  You should post that as an answer. :)

Comment: Arkantos answer is basically the same, you should accept that one.

Comment: @Gustav Yeah, I didn't see that before. The comments updated, but not the answers. Sorry. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue in your code is in the scope definition of your custom directive.

```
scope: {
        data: "="
       }
```

With this, it will look for a `data` attribute on your directive like `<speaker-cards data='speakers'>` and assigns it to `data` property on the isolated scope created for this directive.

But you're looking for `speakers` in your template.

```
<div ng-repeat="speaker in speakers | orderBy: 'SpeakerName'">
```

But there's no `speakers` defined in your current directive scope, there's only `data` property, so you can fix it by changing your template like below.

```
<div ng-repeat="speaker in data | orderBy: 'SpeakerName'">
```

You can also fix this by changing your scope definition to capture `data` attribute from directive as `speakers` in your directive scope.

```
myApp.directive("speakerCards", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "template.html",
      scope: {
            speakers: "=data"
        }
    };
});
```

With this, you don't have to change your template. Here's a sample [Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYVEzp?editors=101) to illustrate this.

Answer (score 1):

Are you defining your var `$scope.speakers` when the Angular Ctrl first run?

If you only define `speakers` at later stage eg: when the function `updateSpeakersList` returns with data, Angular might not have configured `speakers` and might have no watchers in it (due to how dependency injection works in AngularJs).

Add the following line when the angular controller first run (configuration time)

```
$scope.speakers = [];
```

Comment: To add to this, you can leave `$scope.speakers` undefined if you change your directive scope binding to `data: '?='`.